# complexity of quick sort algorithm

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, complexity-theory

The standard worst case complexity of quick sort is O(n^2). What is this worst case and how can I make modifications in such a case to come up with a better behaviour?
This is just a theoretical question.

Comment: Somebody answered this here:
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019528/quick-sort-worst-case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worst case is whenever you choose a pivot, it always turns out to be either the largest or the smallest element in the segment that you're sorting. To improve on the worst case, you need to have a good method of choosing the pivot.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case is when the data is already sorted.

A way to compensate is to randomly choose the first pivot.

Comment: The worst case is contingent: see other answers.

Answer (score 0):

The worst case depends on what partitioning method you are using. In the simplest case the worst case is when the data is already sorted. That's why you don't use it.