# how to understand quick sort algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I am learning quick sort in java, according to the material I have. The best case is the pivot is the median, worst case is when one side of the pivot is always empty.

For the following code, **is "indexPartition" the pivot?** What kind of parameters do you put in the following function **so it will run in the worst situation?**

```
    private void quickSortSegment(E[] list, int start, int end)
{
  if (end-start>1) 
  { 
     int indexPartition = partition(list, start, end);
     quickSortSegment(list, start, indexPartition);
     quickSortSegment(list, indexPartition+1, end);
  }
}

private int partition(E[] list, int start, int end)
{
  E temp; 
  E partitionElement = list[start];
  int leftIndex = start; 
  int rightIndex = end-1;
  while (leftIndex<rightIndex)
  {  
    while (list[leftIndex].compareTo(partitionElement) <= 0 && leftIndex<rightIndex)
    {
        leftIndex++; 
    }
    while (list[rightIndex].compareTo(partitionElement) > 0)
    {
        rightIndex--; 
    }
     if (leftIndex<rightIndex)
     {  
        temp = list[leftIndex];
        list[leftIndex] = list[rightIndex];
        list[rightIndex] = temp;
     }
  }
  list[start] = list[rightIndex];
  list[rightIndex] = partitionElement;
  return rightIndex;
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Quicksort-example.gif

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019528/quick-sort-worst-case

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sorting_quicksort_anim.gif

Comment: I highly recommend watching some videos, you can find really nice youtube videos

Comment: Check my answer out.  Demonstrations can be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the pivot is `partitionElement`. It also seems this code always selects the first element in the sequence to be the pivot. The function will run in all cases including the worst cases, but it will perform badly(have square complexity).

Different people propose different solutions for selecting the pivot but I personally like this one: Select 3 random elements from the interval in consideration, compute their average and use it as pivot.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Quick Sort Video]

This video along with the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) article should clear things up.  Wikipedia is pretty awesome for explaining sorting algorithms.  With respect to your question, `indexPartition` is `rightIndex`, which is the index of `partitionElement`, the pivot.

Answer (score 1):

Something wrong with this method partition(), e.g. for {3,1,2} we'll get {1,3,2}:

```
public class CompareApp {
public static void main(String... args) {
    Integer[] arr = {3, 1, 2};
    quickSortSegment(arr, 0, 2);
    for (Integer i : arr) System.out.println(i);
}

private static <E extends Comparable> void quickSortSegment(E[] list, int start, int end) {
    if (end - start > 1) {
        int indexPartition = partition(list, start, end);
        quickSortSegment(list, start, indexPartition);
        quickSortSegment(list, indexPartition + 1, end);
    }
}


private static <E extends Comparable> int partition(E[] list, int start, int end) {
    E temp;
    E partitionElement = list[start];
    int leftIndex = start;
    int rightIndex = end - 1;
    while (leftIndex < rightIndex) {
        while (list[leftIndex].compareTo(partitionElement) <= 0 && leftIndex < rightIndex) {
            leftIndex++;
        }
        while (list[rightIndex].compareTo(partitionElement) > 0) {
            rightIndex--;
        }
        if (leftIndex < rightIndex) {
            temp = list[leftIndex];
            list[leftIndex] = list[rightIndex];
            list[rightIndex] = temp;
        }
    }
    list[start] = list[rightIndex];
    list[rightIndex] = partitionElement;
    return rightIndex;
}}
```

> java system.compare.CompareApp

1
3
2

Comment: Also it will not sort size=2 arrays (sub-arrays): {3,1} -> {3,1}